# how to localize iOS app bundle display name using xcconfig?

Tags: ios, localization, cfbundledisplayname

I know how to localize app bundle display name in InfoPlist.strings. But I want to change my bundle display name by xcconfig files for different configurations, so is it possible to localize it?